# Why does Multi Objective RL exist?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, optimization, multi-objective-rl

I have recently posted a question here about a problem that I have controlling a robotic arm.
Basically I have a dense reward for the arms position, and a sparse reward for the arms stiffness: [Reward shaping for dense and sparse rewards](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/45049/reward-shaping-for-dense-and-sparse-rewards?noredirect=1#comment65807_45049)

I am using PPO at the moment in my attempts to solve it but with little success. Now I learned about specialised Multi-Objective RL algorithms and think that they might be suited better.

Still I am wondering why that would be or why we would need a separate algorithm for MOO.
**Can we not always put all reward for multiple objectives into some formula to form a single reward?**
Weighted sum, ratio, difference,  whatever?